# Quickblox upload image to custom object

Tags: ios, quickblox, custom-object

I created a custom object field of type file and I tried to upload an image. I have tried both

```
[object.fields setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forKey:@"file"];
```

and

```
[object.fields setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]) forKey:@"file"];
```

but neither works.
Do anyone know how to get this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At now Custom objects don't contain binary data itself. As a possible variant you can do the next:

- load your image as a BLOB (http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-content-ios). After upload you get URL to uploaded file.
- save this url to custom object as a string.

QuickBlox team is going to release iOS SDK v.1.8 with CustomObjects file API soon, feel free to check developers section http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Download_iOS_SDK